# Why does mac iterm and iterm2 not source .bashrc or .bash_profile?

Tags: macos, login, bashrc, .bash-profile

I have ready *many* posts related to login/non-login and interactive/non-interactive. It would be my understanding that .bashrc *should* be sourced from iterm - which is interactive logon shell.

It is not (as evidenced by adding 'echo' statements to both of them).

So then how to fix the userid  to source .bash_profile and .bashrc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most possible reason is that your default `bashrc` file is `~/.profile`. On my `Mavericks` with default `bash` `v3.`, it happens to be like that.